# zf 1: add javascript code to my view

Tags: zend-framework

I trying to add javascript code to my view so i followed [this](http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2010/06/24/zend-framework-inject-javascript-code-in-a-actionview/) tutorial and I added this below to my controller:

```
$scripts = $this->view->inlineScript();
$scripts->appendScript('alert("jfkasd")');
```

But i there is either no alert pop up nor I find any reference to `alert()` function in the source code of the page.

Since I don't know exactly if I write those lines in the action or the view, I also tried this:

```
<!-- /views/scripts/contracts/generalinfo.phtml -->
<?php $scripts = $this->inlineScript() ?>
<?php $scripts->appendScript('alert("jfkasd")') ?>
```

but the result is the same as before..

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to echo out the scripts. Basic idea would be

```
<?php echo $scripts->appendScript('alert("jfkasd")') ?>
```

Or, is set in the controller you would put this in either your view or layout file:

```
<?php echo $this->inlineScript() ?>
```